# Not Able to Attach MSWord Documents in MFMailComposer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In `MFMailComposer` I'm attaching MSWord documents. Those documents are attached to `MFMailComposer`. I sent those documents to another mail address. In the destination mail those attachments are displayed with a download option and not with a view option.

i'm using this code

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.fileString];
NSData *attachments = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[mailView addAttachmentData:attachments mimeType:@"application/pdf/text/msword/csv" fileName:self.useridString];
```

Comment: Could you please share the code you are using to set the attachment?

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct MIME type? References on the web indicate application/msword.

Comment: in my app i want to send file with pdf,msword and text formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set mime type for MSWORD documents..

The `"application/msword"` MIME type is the type for the word 2003 ".doc" files. The correct MIME type for word 2007 ".docx" files is:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

and for more msword mimetypes, use these links [link1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/05/08/office-2007-open-xml-mime-types.aspx) and [link2](http://jameskovacs.com/2007/10/11/configuring-iis6-to-serve-office-2007-file-formats/)

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [picker setSubject:@"Your Subject"];
    [picker addAttachmentData:yourData mimeType:@"application/csv" fileName:@"fileName"];
    [picker addAttachmentData:yourData mimeType:@"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" fileName:@"fileName"];
    }
```

**Edited:**
  Check the url contains which formate. I mean this [url](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/MFMailComposeViewController_class.pdf) contain .pdf and get that pdf. and so on...

```
 NSArray *arrayComp = [self.fileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    NSString *fileType = [[[arrayComp lastObject] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] lastObject];
    NSString *mimeType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/%@",fileType];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.fileString];
    NSData *attachments = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [picker addAttachmentData:attachments mimeType:mimeType fileName:@"fileName"];
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: You have to attach data one by one file types wise.I have edited my code.

Comment: actually those attachment are coming from web service. I don't know that attachment is pdf or word documents or any other.  so now wat i have to do.

Comment: Word to the wise: most email clients will not enjoy seeing this mime type.

Comment: Check the url contains which format. I mean this url http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/MFMailComposeViewController_class.pdf contain .pdf and get that one and so on. I think it will helpful to you.

Comment: @goutham: Can you show me NSLog(@"The String:%@",self.fileString);

Comment: file is  http://Gigpost.testshell.net/AttachMents/b0290981-cc11-4a1f-b4bb-205c837a8a7d_ClickToCall.doc

Comment: you need to check  whether it is doc then change it to msword and docx then change vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document and so on

Comment: how to change programmatically

Comment: Use if conditions and also refer to above links//